# Realtime pixel drawing in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

My app display a long scientific vertically-scrollable picture (1024 x 99999999... px) as a sequence of `QPixmap` 1024x128 blocks. This allows me to scroll a picture with minimal CPU-cost by picking needed blocks from a table: `block_id = y_coord/128`. Also, `QPixmap` is preferred "pixel container" for fast screen output.

But now I have a stream of new data coming to the application and need the new data to be added and displayed at the bottom of the long picture. Minimal portion: `1024x1` (a line). Also, I would like to display each new line as soon as possible (close to real-time). Each new portion of 128 lines will be "packed" to `QPixmap`, but until I received enough data I cannot build a whole block.

What approach should I consider for displaying the new data?

This video gives an idea of "adding new lines of data", except in my case the flow goes up: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dy3zyQNK7jM

Comment: I guess you can just pack new data to some temporary pixmap and draw it at the bottom of the picture and draw the rest the same way you draw it now (with some shifting maybe). When you have received 128 lines, just discard temporary pixmap and pack data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply, directly, modify the bottom row of QPixmaps and `update()` the window (if the bottom row is in range).

You might find using a QImage is more efficient for half-baked rows, depending on how quickly you update/repaint.

Comment: Updaging of a QPixmap is not cheap :)

Comment: No, but updating a QImage is cheaper, as I mentioned. You'll lose speed in rendering, but probably not a lot. You could make the strips 1024*16 or something instead, that should help. *Have you measured it?*

Answer (score 1):

On contemporary Qt, when using the raster backend, `QPixmap` offers no benefits compared to `QImage`. Everything is rendered to a big `QImage` backing buffer that then gets blitted to the screen. So just use `QImage`.

You can have a `QImage` that is 128 pixels high, but you only draw the part of it that was already filled with data. The part without data is either not drawn, or hangs below the visible area of the window, and is thus effectively invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example I put together.  I don't know if it is the most efficient, but it shows off the basic idea you are looking at:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QVector>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QTimerEvent>

#define TILE_HEIGHT 128
#define TILE_WIDTH 1024

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QPixmap generateLine();
public slots:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);
private:
    QGraphicsView * m_view;
    QGraphicsScene * m_scene;
    QVector <QGraphicsPixmapItem *> m_tiles;
    QVector <QGraphicsPixmapItem *> m_lineBuffer;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QPixmap>
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QPaintEngine>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setFixedWidth(TILE_WIDTH);
    this->setCentralWidget(m_view = new QGraphicsView());
    m_scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    m_view->setScene(m_scene);

    QPixmap p(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
    p.fill(Qt::black);
    m_tiles.append(new QGraphicsPixmapItem(p));
    m_tiles.last()->setPos(0,0);
    m_scene->addItem(m_tiles.last());

    qsrand(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch());

    this->startTimer(0);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    // if your generated data is on another thread, you may want to do some thread
    // synchronization with a Mutex and a Mutex Locker so you don't stomp on your
    // buffers

    // static bool busy = false;
    // static int skipCount = 0;
    // if(busy)
    // { 
    //    skipCount++;
    //     qDebug() << "Skipped Line count =" << skipCount;
    //     return;
    // }
    // busy = true;

    // grab a new line
    QPixmap linePix = generateLine();
    int y = m_tiles.size()*TILE_HEIGHT + m_lineBuffer.size()*1;

    // append it to the line buffer
    m_lineBuffer.append(new QGraphicsPixmapItem(linePix));

    // add it to the scene
    m_scene->addItem(m_lineBuffer.last());
    m_lineBuffer.last()->setPos(0, y);

    // scroll it into view
    m_view->ensureVisible(m_lineBuffer.last());

    if(m_lineBuffer.size() >= TILE_HEIGHT)
    {
        // when the line buffer is "full"
        // or ready to be made into a tile

        // compile all the qpixmaps into a single "tile"
        static QRectF source(0,0, TILE_WIDTH, 1);
        QPixmap tile(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);
        QPainter painter;
        painter.begin(&tile);
        for(int i = 0; i < m_lineBuffer.size(); i++)
        {
            painter.drawPixmap(QRectF(0, i, TILE_WIDTH, 1),
                               m_lineBuffer.at(i)->pixmap(),
                                       source);
        }
        painter.end();

        // add it into the tiles list
        m_tiles.append(new QGraphicsPixmapItem(tile));

        // add it to the scene
        m_tiles.last()->setPos(0, (m_tiles.size() - 1)*TILE_HEIGHT);
        m_scene->addItem(m_tiles.last());

        // scroll it into view
        m_view->ensureVisible(m_tiles.last());

        // Clean up the line buffer
        foreach(QGraphicsPixmapItem * pi, m_lineBuffer)
        {
            m_scene->removeItem(pi);
            delete pi;
        }
        m_lineBuffer.clear();
    }
    // busy = false;
}

QPixmap MainWindow::generateLine()
{
    // create a random pixmap of TILE_WIDTH x 1
    static int img_width = TILE_WIDTH;
    QImage img(img_width,1, QImage::Format_RGB16);
    for(int i = 0; i< img_width; i++)
    {
        img.setPixel(i, 0, qrand()%65536);
    }
    return QPixmap::fromImage(img);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showMaximized();

    return a.exec();
}
```